# Detecting Stock Android Browser and Rerouting (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

We have found that the Stock Android Browser on many phones is not working with our app (built in Angular 1). Polyfills did not fix it, and our current solution is to detect this browser and redirect it to a page which basically says "The app works on Firefox and Chrome for Android, please download one of these!"

My current method is putting this script in the head of our HTML, before everything else loads

```
<script>
    var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0;
    var webkitVer = parseInt(/WebKit\/([0-9]+)|$/.exec(navigator.appVersion)[1], 10); 
    var isAOSP = isAndroid && webkitVer <= 534 && navigator.vendor.indexOf('Google') == 0;

    if(isAOSP){
        window.location = "/views/compatibility/compatibility.html";
    }
</script>
```

The only problem is that it isn't working. I tested it using an HTC M8 on browserstack, and it is still loading us into the broken frontpage, not redirecting.

I know the script itself should work because if I change `if (isAOSP == false)...` it will redirect me while I'm on something compatible (like my Desktop). I assume that there's something wrong with the variables, but I wanted to ask if you guys had any suggestions!

Thank you =)

Edit: Solution was simple, and easy to find thanks to user Jaromanda X. By debugging, I found that the browser was using webkit version 537, where I was evaluating things less than 534. Changing to 537 allowed for the redirect.

Comment: so you've determined that `isAOSP` is false, when you expect it to be true, that means one of the other conditions is false ... so, what is `isAndroid` ... true or false? what is `webkitVer` <= 534 or is it > 534? what is `navigator.vendor.indexOf('Google')` 0 or not?

Comment: For fun, I checked running the variables through a console.log() at runtime while using the desktop

`isAndroid: false ; webkitVer: NaN ; isAOSP: false`

This is what I'd expect from the desktop. Any tips for running this same check out on an emulated Android device? So far as I've been able to tell, there isn't a way for me to check the console on an emulated device (about:debug hasn't worked for me on it, and I can't emulate a remote debug)

Comment: use that code to output something to a page, say the content of a div or something

Comment: Did that, and the solution was immediately clear - Thank you! =) The Webkit version was 537, so it was evaluating that as false. Changing it to <= 537 allowed for the redirect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user Jaromanda X commented, we changed our code to detect above 534. This is what the final code looked like:

```
    var navU = navigator.userAgent;
    // Android Mobile
    var isAndroidMobile = navU.indexOf('Android') > -1 && navU.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && navU.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1;
    // Apple webkit
    var regExAppleWebKit = new RegExp(/AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/);
    var resultAppleWebKitRegEx = regExAppleWebKit.exec(navU);
    var appleWebKitVersion = (resultAppleWebKitRegEx === null ? null : parseFloat(regExAppleWebKit.exec(navU)[1]));
    // Chrome
    var regExChrome = new RegExp(/Chrome\/([\d.]+)/);
    var resultChromeRegEx = regExChrome.exec(navU);
    var chromeVersion = (resultChromeRegEx === null ? null : parseFloat(regExChrome.exec(navU)[1]));
    // Native Android Browser
    var isAndroidBrowser = isAndroidMobile && (appleWebKitVersion !== null && appleWebKitVersion <= 537) || (chromeVersion !== null && chromeVersion <= 38);

    //If isAndroidBrowser, redirect 
    if(isAndroidBrowser){
        window.location = "/views/compatibility/compatibility.html";
    }
```